# Visual Studio Macro - Read first X lines instead of entire document

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, macros

I've got a macro that updates a copyright header with the most recent edit date.

The problem I have is that the macro currently reads through the entire file rather than just the first 6 lines (which is all it needs).

Is there a way to get the Macro to only read the first "X" lines rather than the entire file?

```
Private selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
Private Sub UpdateCopyrightHeader()

    selection.StartOfDocument()
    selection.EndOfDocument(True)

    Dim content As String = selection.Text
    Dim result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(content, regex, "<lastedit>" & FormatDateTime(Date.Now, vbLongDate) & "</lastedit>")

    selection.Delete()
    selection.Collapse()
    Dim ed As EditPoint = selection.TopPoint.CreateEditPoint()
    ed.Insert(result)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`LineDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.textselection.linedown.aspx) instead of`selection.EndOfDocument(True)`:

```
selection.StartOfDocument()
selection.LineDown(True, 6)
```

Comment: perfect this works.  As a subsequent question.. .do I have to run the StartOfDocument or does it suffice to ONLY read the 6th line?